# css блок вымещает блок

Tags: css

Привет. У меня возникла такая проблема.
[image: 1]

Вот. есть блок 1 и блок 2. Вроде всё нормально, но при ресайзе происходит вот такое: [image: 2]

Вот css

```css
/*блок 1*/
.manga{
 border-radius:5px;
 width:82%;
 
 float:left;
  
 border: 1px black solid;
}
/*блок 2*/
.user{
    
    float:right;
 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не рекомендуется использовать float в 2017 году, если в этом нет необходимости, например из-за поддержки старых браузеров.

```css
div {
  min-height: 50vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*блок 1*/

.manga {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 82%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px black solid;
}


/*блок 2*/

.user {
  width: 18%;
  float: right;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="user"></div>
<div class="manga"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чем регулируется ширина блока справа? Если у него фиксированная ширина (например, определяемая его содержимым), то блоки в какой-то момент перестанут помещаться в ширину родителя.

Вот так:

```css
div {
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.manga {
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
}


/*блок 2*/

.user {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="manga"></div>
<div class="user"></div>
```

Comment: Кстати, у тс на картинке левый блок меньше по высоте. Интересно, это важно? )

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Не думаю. Дело, скорее всего, в ширине.